# Odd SVN Checkout failures occur frequenctly on VMWare virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, svn, hudson

We've recently been experiencing seemingly random SVN checkout failures on our Hudson build system.

We are occasionally receiving the following SVN error when our Hudson build jobs checkout source via the Hudson Subversion plug-in (which uses svn kit):

> ERROR: Failed to check out `http://server/svnroot/trunk`
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/svnroot/!svn/vcc/default) 
>   svn: REPORT request failed on '/svnroot/!svn/vcc/default'

This issue seems to only occur when checking out from our Virtual Machines (Windows XP, Fedora 9, Fedora 12) using Hudson's SVN Plug-in.  Systems that use the traditional SVN client seem to work.

- SVN Server version: 1.6.6
- Hudson version: 1.377
- Hudson SVN Plugin Version: 1.17

Answer (score 0):

If I look at your URL, it looks like you are downloading the whole repository (or trunk of all of your projects). How much do you check out? Wouldn't it be better only to download the project that you need (e.g. http://server/svnroot/trunk/project)?

Have a look at the following link. It explains what might be the problem when downloading to much data at once.

http://server/svnroot/trunk

BTW, I think this question is bound to get more answers on Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks I'll move this to StackOverflow, I wasn't sure if it belonged over there.  The path is actually correct, we are checking out a subset of trunk, the path is actually http://server/svnroot/project/projectTrunk/.  Thanks for the help